# Use of CASE in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.var = table3.var
INNER JOIN table4 ON table1.field = table4.field
```

but I only want to include the table3 join if a variable has a certain value (iMarket=250 and above)

I'm trying to get this sort of condition working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
CASE 
   WHEN iMarket > 250 
     THEN INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.var = table3.var
END
INNER JOIN table4 on table1.field = table4.field
```

This is pseudo-code but it approximates to what I'm trying to do. Nothing works. Is there an easier way of doing it? I want to exclude this join because it always fails if that variable is below a certain value. Thank you all!

Comment: The CASE statement in SQL can only return a value.   It cannot direct control-of-flow.

Comment: Actually, `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - not a statement - and an expression can only be evaluated to one (possibly of many possible) values - it cannot be used to "conditionally" join tables ...

Answer (score 3):

As easy to include condition in join `on` clause:

```
SELECT * from table1
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.key=table2.key
INNER JOIN table3 on iMarket>250 and table1.var=table3.var
INNER JOIN table4 on table1.field=table4.field
```

Remember than you should use **outer joins** if you need all values from other tables despite the fact that they are no matches for `table3`, perhaps you are looking for this behavior:

```
SELECT * from table1
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.key=table2.key
INNER JOIN table4 on table1.field=table4.field
left outer join   --<--
           table3 on iMarket>250 and table1.var=table3.var
```

Comment: Thank you all - you've been very helpful!